# How does the openshift build system work?

Tags: node.js, openshift

I'm struggling with how to set up an openshift build, where I have two projects in one. Both (the frontend and the node backend) have their own package.json but only the latter needs to be started.

I'm using the hooks in the .openshift directory, but there seems to be more 'magic' going on in the background. For example nowhere in my build code there is an npm start declared. Openshift seems to run the command automatically. Is there maybe a way to deactivate this behaviour? What is going on the background? Is the build-process defined by the package I'm using? And if so, how to change it?

If all fails, I really would like to use an external build-server. Is that possible?